# Retornar colunas de acordo com critérios sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como eu poderia retornar o nome das colunas de uma tabela de acordo com critérios de busca? Quero retornar as colunas que estão com opção ‘S’,  todos os campos é um char de 1 que recebe “s” ou “n”

```
select 
   b.livros,
   b.jogos,
   b.cinema
from
   tb_cadastro_usuario a 
   inner join tb_assuntos_interesse b on a.idusuario = b.idusuario
```

Comment: Você quer saber se o usuário se interessa por livros e/ou jogos e/ou cinema? Exemplo, eu estou cadastrado e me interesso por cinema e jogos... Ao me buscar pelo ID vc retornaria Interesses: Jogos, Cinema ? Tipo issio?

Comment: Where (b.livros = 's' or b.jogos = 's' or b.cinema = 's')     um modelo ruim todavia pois se quiser incluir 'teatro' será preciso criar outra coluna , pense numa tabela de INTERESSES e uma de ligação INTERESSE_USUARIO.

Comment: vc quer altera o nome das colunas de quer forma, pode detalhar melhor, ou por o que vc espera do seu select